# Android - How to change texts in the preferences activity dynamically?

Tags: android, android-activity, settings, android-preferences

Hello fellow programmers, I have a little problem with Preferences activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

I've got just one preference category and a listPreference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/basic_settings" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="70"
        android:entries="@array/listArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
        android:key="updates_interval"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:summary="@string/SOME_SUMMARY"
        android:title="@string/SOME_TITLE" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I need to have the selected value (the default one or the user defined one) written in the summary of the listPreference, for example:
We will have at least 70 characters.

How can I do this from the code?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try like this..

```
 Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("updates_interval");<-- your preferences key
 customPref.setSummary("desired string");
```

Comment: Thanks ! :) I didn't see the findPreference method.

Answer (score 1):

here is a short example:

```
Preference etp = (Preference) findPreference("the_pref_key");
etp.setSummary("New summary");
```

This requires that you display your preferences either from a PreferenceActivity or from a PreferenceFragment, since findPreference() is a method of these classes. You most likely do that already.

To change the summary every time the user changes the actual preference, use a [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) and check if the relevant key changed in the callback. After it has changed, just edit the summary like above.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of ListPreference in which you set an [OnPreferenceChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) from which you will have access to the new value, and set the text on your ListPreference. I think the [setSummary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setSummary%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) function on the ListPreference will update the text under the name of the preference. If that doesn't work you can also override getView() to implement your own custom view for the Preference on which you can set the text directly.